# Custom dialog box not showing

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing some javascript and HTML, and I want to do custom dialog boxes for user error handling(not filling in fields). For some reason the boxes do not show up when the user error occurs. My Java scrip and html follows:

```
        <script>$(document).ready(function(){
              $('#submit_button').click(function(){
                    ShowCustomDialog();
                });
                     });

        function ShowCustomDialog()
        {
            var name = document.getElementById('name');
            var address = document.getElementById('email');
            var reason =  document.getElementById('reason');
            var message = document.getElementById('message');
            if(name.value == ''){
                ShowDialogBox('Warning','Enter your name','Ok','', 'GoToAssetList',null);
                return false;
            }
            if(email.value == ''){
                ShowDialogBox('Warning','Enter your email.','Ok','', 'GoToAssetList',null);
                return false;
            }
            if(reason.value == ''){
                ShowDialogBox('Warning','Select a reason','Ok','', 'GoToAssetList',null);
                return false;
            }
            if(message.value == ''){
                ShowDialogBox('Warning','Enter a message.','Ok','', 'GoToAssetList',null);
                return false;
            }

        }

        function ShowDialogBox(title, content, btn1text, btn2text, functionText, parameterList) {
            var btn1css;
            var btn2css;

            if (btn1text == '') {
                btn1css = "hidecss";
            } else {
                btn1css = "showcss";
            }

            if (btn2text == '') {
                btn2css = "hidecss";
            } else {
                btn2css = "showcss";
            }
            $("#lblMessage").html(content);

            $("#dialog").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                title: title,
                modal: true,
                width: '400px',
                height: 'auto',
                bgiframe: false,
                hide: { effect: 'scale', duration: 400 },

                buttons: [
                                {
                                    text: btn1text,
                                    "class": btn1css,
                                    click: function () {

                                        $("#dialog").dialog('close');

                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    text: btn2text,
                                    "class": btn2css,
                                    click: function () {
                                        $("#dialog").dialog('close');
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
            });
        }</script><form method="post" action="MAILTO:me" enctype="text/plain" onsubmit=" return ShowCustomDialog()">

  <div class="row">
    <label>Your Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" size="20" />
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label>Your E-mail:</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" size="20" />
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label>Reason for Report:</label>
    <select id="reason" name="reason" />
    <option value="">Please Select...</option>
    <option value="bug">Bug Report</option>
    <option value="feature">Feature</option>
    <option value="tech_support">Technical Support</option>
    <option value="other">Other...</option>
    </select>

  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <label>Your Message:</label>
    <textarea type="text" id="message" name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea>
  </div>
  <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Send E-mail" />
  <div id="dialog" title="Alert message" style="display: none">
    <div class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">
      <p>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0"></span>
        <label id="lblMessage">
        </label>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I would be grateful for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a click event on a button, you have to return false or use e.preventDefault(). Otherwise, the button submits the page and you never see the dialog box.

For example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          $('#submit_button').click(function(e){
            if(!ShowCustomDialog()) {
              e.preventDefault()
            }
          });
});
```

With my example, you should add a return true to your ShowCustomDialog function.

```
function ShowCustomDialog()
{
   ...
   if(message.value == ''){
     ShowDialogBox('Warning','Enter a message.','Ok','', 'GoToAssetList',null);
     return false;
   }

   return true;
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the alert('you pressed...');...
I forgot to take that out after testing initially

Comment: Thanks for the help, @Robbert. However, For some reason when I run it, the dialog window does not show up on the webpage, only through a online compiler.

Comment: It's working for me: https://jsfiddle.net/wko763cd/.  Did you add the e in the line `$('#submit_button').click(function(e){`?

Comment: Yes, I still don't get the message to come up ever. I wonder if it's an issue with chrome.

Comment: I run chrome.  Is the JSFiddle not working for you, either?

Comment: The JSFiddle is working. Browser, however is not working.

Comment: Make sure you have linked jQuery and jQuery-UI Dialog code.

Answer (score 0):

why you don't use modal see:

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

or bootstrap modals:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals